# Keyboard Focus Lag

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am building an application in WPF. It consists of a complex background (Canvas containing 3000 rectangles) and five buttons on top of that. The only "Focusable" And "HitVisible" elements are the five buttons. I am having a problem where if I use tab-targeting and focus the last element, there is significant delay between pressing tab and having it focus the first element again. Is there anything I can do without having to remove my background?

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
{
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();

    rectangle.Width  = 60;
    rectangle.Height = 60;
    rectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush (Color.FromArgb
        ((byte) random.Next (0, 12), 255, 255, 255));

    Canvas.SetLeft (rectangle, x * 30 - 5);
    Canvas.SetTop  (rectangle, y * 30 - 5);

    uiCanvasBackground.Children.Add (rectangle);
}
```

Comment: Please show  some sample code how you generate one of those 3000 rectangles that should not get the focus.

Comment: Question has been edited with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create more lightweight objects such as System.Windows.Media.DrawingVisual objects and draw the rectangle in the drawing context. These would be hosted in a Framework element acting as an ItemsControl.

This great article describes how you could implement an efficient ItemsControl:
[Writing More Efficient ItemsControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483292.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've added two lines to your code and I hope that will solve your problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
{
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();

    rectangle.Width = 60;
    rectangle.Height = 60;

    // I added the following two lines
    rectangle.Focusable = false;
    rectangle.SetValue(KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStopProperty, false);
    rectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb((byte)random.Next(0, 12), 255, 255, 255));

    Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, x * 30 - 5);
    Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, y * 30 - 5);

    uiCanvasBackground.Children.Add(rectangle);
}
```

Comment: No it didn't unfortunately. Setting the visibility to hidden works, which is strange. Hopefully I can find another alternative.

Comment: You said, that you have 3000 controls on one form. That is pretty much, isn't it? So it takes a lot of time, when the KeyboardNavigation Handler has to search for the next valid control to get the focus. Maybe you can do a workaround in the LostFocus event, or - possible better - in the keydown event of a control that is fuocusable, set the focus direct to the next valid control on tab key pressed and set the event as handled.

Answer (score 0):

If it is related to the tabbing then try setting the attached KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation on the Canvas to None so the framework will skip the Canvas and its descendants when evaluating the tab stops.